# How to delete a row from a Kendo Grid with confirmation and passing in the selected ID into the Destroy method

Tags: c#, kendo-grid

How can I delete a row from a Kendo Grid with confirmation and passing in the selected ID into the Destroy method? Here's my cshtml code:

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<EmailTemplateEditor.Models.EmailTemplate>()
    .Name("EmailTemplates")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.ID).ClientTemplate("<a href='/EmailTemplate/EmailTemplate/#=ID#'>#=ID#</a>");            
        columns.Bound(c => c.Name);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Subject);
        columns.Bound(c => c.OperationalBrand);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Body);
        columns.Bound(c => c.DateAdded).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
        columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(110);
    })
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 700px;" })
        .Scrollable()
        .Groupable()
        .AutoBind(true)
        .Sortable()
        .Filterable()
        .Pageable(pageable => pageable
            .PageSizes(true)
            .ButtonCount(5))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.ID))
                        .Read(read => read.Action("GetEmailTemplates", "Home"))                            
                .PageSize(20)
                .ServerOperation(true)                    
                .Destroy(update => update.Action("Delete", "Home", Model.ID))
        )
)
```

And here is my controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, int ID)
    {
        Worker.DeleteEmailTemplate(ID);
        return View();
    }
```

When I run this, I get an error saying that Model.ID is null. If I can't access the current row's ID in that way, how can I do it? I'd really like to avoid having to refactor this to use a "transport" style of datasource, but if that's the only way to do it, please let me know. Here's what the UI looks like:

[image: UI screenshot]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change your Destroy command to the following.

```
.Destroy(update => update.Action("Delete", "Home"))
```

Then your controller to:

```
public ActionResult Delete([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, EmailTemplate myModel)
```

Then you can access the id using

```
myModel.ID
```

Comment: That was the first thing I tried and the method never got called. If I remove the EmailTemplate myModel input param, then it gets called, but then I lose the input I needed.

Comment: It should work. Suggestion to debug (IE). Open Developer Tools (F12), then Network tab, Enable network traffic capturing.  You will be able to see your request /Home/Delete and open it and see what error you get. It may be 404 error. I guess you have installed all the Kendo libraries properly.

Comment: It's showing a status 500 because http://localhost:55299/Home/Delete doesn't match up due to the EmailTemplate param on the end of the input list, I'm guessing.

Comment: It suggests there is an exception thrown when initialize the EmailTemplate object at server side by the framework. Is EmailTemplate a class auto generated by Entity Framework (Domain Model)? If yes I suggest to create your own View Model such as ViewModelEmailTemplate class and have only basic data types. If it is not a domain model you may post the EmailTemplate class here. Happy to have a look.